# How to unpack tuple in PostgreSQL SELECT?

Tags: postgresql

As of some quirks in our DB model I am faced with a table that optionally links to itself. I want to write a query that selects each row in a way that either the original row is returned or - if present - the linked row.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(r2.*, r1.*)
FROM mytable r1
LEFT JOIN mytable r2
ON r1.sub_id = r2.id
```

While this works, all data is returned in one column 'COALESCE' as tuples instead of the actual table columns.

How can I unpack those tuples to get the actual table rows or 'fix' the query to avoid it altogether?

Comment: Try `(COALESCE(r2.*, r1.*)).*`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, that works perfectly. It would be great if you could turn it into an answer so that I can give you proper credit.